# Is it possible to build MSBuild files (visual studio sln) from the command line in Mono?

Tags: msbuild, mono

Is it possible to build Visual Studio solutions without having to fire up MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Current status (Mono 2.10, 2011): xbuild is now able to build all versions of Visual Studio / MSBuild projects, including .sln files. Simply run `xbuild` just as you would execute `msbuild` on Microsoft .Net Framework. You don't need Monodevelop installed, xbuild comes with the standard Mono installation.

If your build uses custom tasks, they should still work if they don't depend on Windows executables (such as `rmdir` or `xcopy`).

When you are editing project files, use standard Windows path syntax - they will be converted by xbuild, if necessary. One important caveat to this rule is case sensitivity - don't mix different casings of the same file name. If you have a project that does this, you can enable compatibility mode by invoking `MONO_IOMAP=case xbuild foo.sln` (or try `MONO_IOMAP=all`). Mono has a page describing more advanced [MSBuild project porting](http://www.mono-project.com/Porting_MSBuild_Projects_To_XBuild) techniques.

Mono 2.0 answer (2008): <strike>[xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build) is not yet complete (it works quite well with VS2005 .csproj files, has problems with VS2008 .csproj and does not handle .sln). Mono 2.1 plans to merge the code base of mdtool (MonoDevelop command line build engine) into it, but currently [mdtool](http://www.monodevelop.com/MonoDevelop_1.0_Released#Command_line_tools) is a better choice. `mdtool build -f:project.sln` or [`man mdtool`](http://ubuntu.dustinkirkland.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/mdtool.html) if you have MonoDevelop installed.</strike>

Comment: apparently mdtool has been renamed to mdrun

Comment: It's the other way round, you have an outdated MonoDevelop.

Comment: xbuild from 2.10.9 not giving me any joy. "error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|web" is invalid" -- despite using /p:Platform="Any CPU" as advised in the error message.

Answer (score 18):

for now as per August 2017 we can use

### msbuild

command as xbuild is depreciated.

Comment: msbuild is not part of Debian so far

Answer (score 7):

xbuild now supports solutions and projects, both VS2005 and VS2008.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for xbuild:
http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build