# Compiling Visual Studio 2008 Project with Mono

Tags: visual-studio, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i build a visual studio solution using xbuild (from Mono)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254722/how-can-i-build-a-visual-studio-solution-using-xbuild-from-mono)

How to compile a visual studio project/solution with Mono ?

If this is possible, Will the output run without installing .NET Framework ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254722/how-can-i-build-a-visual-studio-solution-using-xbuild-from-mono

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  Mono [has xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build), an implementation of msbuild which is used by Visual Studio to build VB.NET and C# projects (but not VC++).  As is typical for Mono, this is a work in progress, be sure to check the todo items to see how suitable it is for your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely check out MonoDevelop.  They actually answer this question in their [FAQ](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f).