# building xbuild into visual studio addin

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-addins, xbuild

im looking for a way to implement a addin that can convert a C# solution into a mono compiled exe, so i can use it on a linux and mac environment that have the mono framework installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to build MSBuild files (visual studio sln) from the command line in Mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790/is-it-possible-to-build-msbuild-files-visual-studio-sln-from-the-command-line-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in a .Net exe and a Mono exe.  Just compile your solution like you normally would in Visual Studio, then run you exe with Mono instead of .Net.

Comment: what im looking to do, is compile with xbuild and return the output of errors (if any), and if no errors, then build and run through cmd.

Comment: because if i just compile with msbuild then any mono related errors wont be displayed

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with Visual Studio and Mono, you should compile against a [Mono Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437286/need-profile-for-mono-3-0-on-windows), this helps minimizing potential errors.

If you're really looking for way to integrate XBuild into Visual Studio, you could

- Add XBuild as Tool in Visual Studio (Tools / External Tools) or
- If you are using VS2012 - you can use and try out [MonoHelper](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cb83d210-b09f-4e21-949e-81ad23684c78), a little tool I created for learning purpose