# mono: Building a .Net solution at the command line on Linux

Tags: .net, ubuntu, mono

I have recently installed mono on my Linux box, in order to be able to do some .Net programming in a more familiar environment.

I am trying to build a **solution** from the command line without having to fireup the heavy monodevelop. On windows this can be done using Msbuild.exe. I cannot seem to find that file with the mono tools.

The nearest is **mdtool** which (if I understand correctly) is used to build individual projects instead of an entire solution).

How may I build an **entire solution** from the command line on Linux using mono?

BTW, I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Simply run xbuild just as you would execute msbuild on Microsoft .Net Framework. You don't need Monodevelop installed, xbuild comes with the standard Mono installation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56113/73381
(possible duplicate)

Comment: xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead (as of 2022)