# Compile VS2010 c# solution (project) on ubuntu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ubuntu, mono

What's the best way to build a c# solution made with Visual Studio on Ubuntu? Is there a way to convert the .sln file to a makefile? Should I use Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do would be to use [`Moma`](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to check to see if your program will run under `Mono` as is. You can also use [`MonoDevelop`](http://monodevelop.com/) which can use Visual Studio Projects.

From their faq: *In fact, since MonoDevelop 2.0 the default project format has been VS2008-style MSBuild projects, but VS2005 and VS2010 formats are also handled.*

Answer (score 0):

C# is a .NET language, .NET is a Windows-based framework. It has been ported to Linux operating systems (Ubuntu included) via the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). So yes, you need to use Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Mono is the best I've tried. It says on [their homepage](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) that they are binary compatible between each other, so if it's already built, you could just run it on Mono. No need to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Mono if you want to use a process like MsBuild.  Mono has xBuild that is similar.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790/is-it-possible-to-build-msbuild-files-visual-studio-sln-from-the-command-line) has some information about using Mono.